# appropriate usage of hidden_fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise, parameters

I am sending one parameter ("designer" or "developer") to register form prepared by Devise and I want to add this parameter to devise model.

My question is if assigning parameter to hidden_field is appropriate solution.

From this view I'm redirecting to user registration form

```
<%= link_to "Register as Owner", new_user_registration_path(:role => 'owner') %>
<%= link_to "Register as Employee",  new_user_registration_path(:role => 'employee' ) %>
```

User registration form

```
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>

  <%= f.hidden_field :role, :value => params[:type]%>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email %><br />
    <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password %>
    <% if @minimum_password_length %>
    <em>(<%= @minimum_password_length %> characters minimum)</em>
    <% end %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off" %>
 </div>

 <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "off" %>
 </div>

 <div class="actions">
   <%= f.submit "Sign up" %>
 </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

As long as the param doesn't contain sensitive information (passwords etc) as you say it doesn't, there isn't a problem with your implementation.